# Numbers that are emirps

Tags: java, primes

So i need to print out the first 100 emirps number. I got the prime and reverse it. But for some reason it still print out a few number wrong, i.e. it prints out 101, which is not an emirps. Is it something wrong with my method to determine if the prime is an emirp?

```
//Method to know if the prime is a emirp
public static boolean isEmirp(int x){
    return isPrime(x) && isPrime(reverse(x));

}
//Method that reverses the prime
public static int reverse(int r){
    if(r<10) return r;
    return switchnum(r%10,r/10);

}
//Method that creates the emirp/reverse prime
public static int switchnum(int a, int b){
    if(b<1) return a;
    return switchnum(a*10+b%10,b/10);
}
```

Comment: You should additionally check `if (x != reverse(x))` to exclude numbers like `11` or `101`.

Comment: @Tom Where should i check it? Before or after i reverses?

Comment: You could include it into your `isPrime` method: `return (x != reverse(x)) && isPrime(x) && isPrime(reverse(x))`. Actual, there is no need to uses parentheses here, but the return statement appears more structured with them. If this works, consider to include following line `int reverse = reverse(x)` and use this variable in that return statement instead of calling the `reverse` method twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverse method and thereby switchnum method you have shared would work only for single or two digit integers.

A safer way to reverse might be :

```
    public int reverse(Integer reversable)
    {
        String reversableString = String.valueOf(reversable);
        return Integer.valueOf(new StringBuilder(reversableString).reverse().toString());
    }
```

Edit :

You should additionally check for non-palindromicity as mentioned in the comments :

```
public static boolean isEmirp(int x){

    int reverseOfX = reverse(x);
    return x != reverseOfX && isPrime(x) && isPrime(reverseOfX);

}
```

Comment: What method would be better to use then?

Comment: I have included both methods